# Where is the client folder of wagtail on windows 10

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I use pip to install wagtail on my computer. Its operating system is windows 10. In my project, I need to customise the admin UI, mainly to modify the css file in client folder. The folder client is peer to folder wagtai on github. But I can not find the client folder on my computer.

How to find the client folder?

Wish for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `client` folder is not part of the installed Wagtail package - instead, the package contains compiled and minified versions of the CSS and JavaScript assets as part of the Django apps that make up Wagtail, for example under `wagtail/admin/static/wagtailadmin/css/`. This is because Wagtail's stylesheets are written in [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) and need to be compiled using a Node / NPM-based toolchain to be usable in the browser, and end users of Wagtail aren't expected to have this toolchain installed.

As a result, making arbitrary customisations to Wagtail's CSS isn't formally supported - to do it, you'll need to start from a checkout from Github, and [set up a dev environment as per the documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/contributing/developing.html). As of Wagtail 2.12 it is possible to [customise the colour scheme using CSS variables](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html#custom-user-interface-colors), though.